# Multiple inserts from multiple WITH/CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  col1 character varying(50),
  mydate timestamp without time zone
);
```

I want to insert data to this table, but also I want to store the maximum id from my source:

```
insert into mytable (select myid, col1, mydate from sourcetable);
```

I don't have a myid  column in mytable, and I can't ask later something like this: `select max(myid) from sourcetable` because I'm getting a snapshot and the sourcetable is a transactional table (hundreds of new records by second) so I need to get the maximum id from that snapshot

I tried something like this:

```
with query1 as (select myid, col1, mydate from sourcetable),
query2 as (select max(myid) id from query1)
insert into mytable (select co1, mydate from query1);
update anothertable set value=(select myid from query2) where col2='avalue';
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "query2" does not exist
LINE 1: update anothertable set value=(select myid from query2) wher...
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Change the second *with* to a comma: `with query2 as ...` -->> `, query2 as ...`

Comment: @joop the query was without "with query2 as" in the first place. My bad. I'll edit the question

Comment: `... 1, mydate from query1);` after the `;` the two CTEs have gone out scope. (they are only valid inside the current statement)

Comment: Thank for the downvote. im just trying to help and got downvote.

Comment: @AdrianHartanto I did not downvote anyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have *two* queries after the CTEs.  Only one.  The CTE is connected to the queries.  So, just add another CTE.  Something like this:

```
with query1 as (
      select myid, col1, mydate
      from sourcetable
     ),
     query2 as (
      select max(myid) as id
      from query1
     ),
     i as (
      insert into mytable   -- You should really list the columns here
          select co1, mydate
          from query1
     )
update anothertable
    set value = (select myid from query2)
    where col2 = 'avalue';
```

Comment: BTW, how to make it work with MS SQL Server 2017? According to documentation, "CTE_query_definition specifies a SELECT statement". So, it cannot include INSERT. What i need to do is having bunch of rows, make INSERT into two tables per one loop step.. Only cursors? :(

Comment: @Alexander . . . If you have a question about SQL Server, then ask another question.  This answer is specific to Postgres.

Comment: There are 3 similar questions regarding PostgreSQL, but 0 regarding SqlServer. From documentation seems that it's not possible: `A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement`
Creating temporary VIEW can be used as a workaround...